# Не работает MutationObserver

Tags: javascript, observer

Где я не прав?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">


const observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
    if (mutation.attributeName === 'class') {
      centerModal();
       console(loh);
    };
  });
});

const up = document.getElementsByClassName('uploaded-documents')[0];
observer.observe(up, {
  childList: true,
  attributes: true
});

function centerModal () {
    let paret = document.getElementsByClassName('upload__table')[0];
                   
    let d = document.createElement('div');
    d.innerHTML = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/70y94zG1-jU" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
        d.className='vid_verif';
        paret.appendChild(d);
        console(lgfoh);
}


</script>
```

Comment: Код должен поймать добавление класса  uploaded-documents и вставить элемент  iframe в конец блока upload__table, но ни ошибок ни выполнения кода я не получаю

Comment: Console так не работает, нужно console.log(...), возможно в этом проблема. Или у вас есть своя реализация console.

Comment: @МаксПетренко дал ответ, прикрутил обработчик события по клику, чтобы класс менялся - `iframe` вставляется

Comment: с консолью лохонулся, не обратил внимание, это не обязательная деталь

Answer (score 0):

Нужно, чтобы произошла мутация - изменение класса элемента `.uploaded-documents`. К консоли обращаются так - `console.log()`, аргумент `log` - либо выражение, либо строка.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('uploaded-documents')[0].addEventListener('click', ()=> {
  event.target.classList.add('mutate');
});

const observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
    if (mutation.attributeName === 'class') {
      centerModal();
       console.log('check first');
    };
  });
});

const up = document.getElementsByClassName('uploaded-documents')[0];
observer.observe(up, {
  childList: true,
  attributes: true
});

function centerModal () {
    let paret = document.getElementsByClassName('upload__table')[0];
                   
    let d = document.createElement('div');
    d.innerHTML = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/70y94zG1-jU" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
        d.className='vid_verif';
        paret.appendChild(d);
        console.log('check');
}
```

```css
.uploaded-documents {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="uploaded-documents"></div>
<div class="upload__table"></div>
```

Comment: Мутации есть, так как я этот код встраиваю в cms и хочу добавить блок при входе в личный кабинет, когда в него входишь, появляется класс у div'а что и является событием мутации

Comment: @МаксПетренко как это происходит?

Comment: Как происходит вход в личный кабинет?  после ввода логина и пароля по клику на див

Comment: @МаксПетренко я имел в виду, перезагружается ли страница?

Comment: Да, перезагружается

Comment: @МаксПетренко смотрите - вы загружаете новую страницу с этим скриптом, происходит переход с на другую, вы сможете отследить мутацию только на загружаемой странице, если скрипт уже на загружаемой странице добавляет класс элементу, то происходит мутация. если вы просто загружаете страницу с таким же элементом, но у него другой класс, прописанный в html - то это не мутация, это не относится к элементу с предыдущей страницы никак

Comment: вроде понял, но как победить личный кабинет так и не понял =)